# R/ date change data is impossible to do

Tags: r

Hi I need help with this assignment for my Master Thesis
The data i collected and that I have cleaned up is written differently from what you would expect (the date data).
I can't format the cell in order to make it change from integral to date

```
show(df$created_at)
   [1] 1621558851 1602599250 1591830172 1610439747 1612037008 1608143708 1612320648 1587634534 1611184343 1607536771
```

The cells are formatted in the way above and represent the moment the project was created (there are 2400 entries in total)
If i either use the mdy function or one of the packages for this, the whole data from my folder changes into NA

I must admit, I really suck at R, so I tried to format it in excel, with no success either ?
Any idea on how to fix this ?

For your info, I am trying to do a time series regression and this is the way the data is formated in my the other folder

```
[1] "2021-12-27T00:41:23.000Z" "2021-12-10T03:08:43.000Z" "2021-12-25T20:59:27.000Z" "2021-12-16T22:19:53.000Z"
   [5] "2021-12-30T01:46:01.000Z" "2021-12-26T20:55:36.000Z" "2021-12-26T19:12:40.000Z" "2021-12-27T03:54:10.000Z"
   [9] "2021-12-26T19:24:33.000Z" "2021-12-26T17:58:35.000Z" "2021-12-26T12:53:47.000Z" "2021-12-27T02:27:02.000Z"
  [13] "2021-12-15T05:08:29.000Z" "2021-12-17T18:47:16.000Z" "2021-12-26T14:34:38.000Z" "2021-12-21T13:00:58.000Z"
```

Thank you for your help and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

These look like POSIX times, which are the integer number of seconds since midnight on 1st January 1970. So you can do:

```r
as.POSIXct(df$created_at, origin = '1970-01-01')
#>  [1] "2021-05-21 02:00:51 BST" "2020-10-13 15:27:30 BST" "2020-06-11 00:02:52 BST"
#>  [4] "2021-01-12 08:22:27 GMT" "2021-01-30 20:03:28 GMT" "2020-12-16 18:35:08 GMT"
#>  [7] "2021-02-03 02:50:48 GMT" "2020-04-23 10:35:34 BST" "2021-01-20 23:12:23 GMT"
#> [10] "2020-12-09 17:59:31 GMT"
```